# Send a message to console about connection established or refused

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, output

I'm working on a NodeJS+Express+Mongo exercise, the lines that I'm using to connect to MongoDB are these ones:

```
const app = express();
const store = new MongoDBStore({
  uri: MONGODB_URI,
  collection: "sessions",
});
```

The connection is working but I would like to send a console.log with the output, either "connection established" or "couldn't connect". Do you have any hints how can I accomplish this task?

Thanks a lot

Comment: The [README for the package that exports the `MongoDBStore` class](https://github.com/mongodb-js/connect-mongodb-session/blob/master/README.md) contains explicit examples on how to handle `error` events, and [its source code](https://github.com/mongodb-js/connect-mongodb-session/blob/master/index.js) shows it emits several other events, a subset of which seemingly matching your requirements. Can you elaborate as to why this doesn’t meet your requirements, or what you’ve tried so far unsuccessfully to meet them in light of this documentation’s guidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried to use `MongoClient.connect` method? You can pass a callback with a `console.log` to inform the status of the connection.
You can see about this here: https://www.tabnine.com/code/javascript/functions/mongodb/MongoClient